# Deleting folder and script after execution

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to run a script that is deployed by SCCM in a randomly named folder in computers. I need to make sure that after the execution is completed, the script and the folder is deleted. I found various posts where the folder name was specific but in my case, the folder name differs every time. I am new to PSScripts and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please give some example folders for more understanding of problem

Comment: If you go to the below path, there are random folders created when something gets deployed by SCCM:

C:\Windows\ccmcache

This might help...